# How to make items responsive in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I Want to make my form items responsive when re-size application window like the websites but i can't do it.

I want to make it always in the center of the application window i was used "anchor" property but it doesn't do it.

there is any way to do this ??

Comment: I seem to remember an almost identical question from yesterday, although the question appears not to exist anymore. It would help if you explain what you mean by "Responsive".

Comment: responsive(AutoScaling)

Comment: By combining docking and anchor usually. 
You'd better be using WPF if working on a new project. Windows Forms is so ... old.

Comment: @SagePourpre You can't have both dock and anchor. If you set one of them the other disables

Comment: Yeah, I commented on that question from yesterday. Can't find it either. Hopefully it wasn't you who posted and deleted it, the Stack Overflow gods will not smile kindly upon your for abusing the system like that. Anyway, the message from the comment is the same. You can do this by judicious use of the Anchor/Dock properties, as well as by placing the controls into either TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel controls. If you are having an actual problem, post code that reproduces it. We call that a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can centre a control on the form by using CSS. For example:

```html
    div.deskTop
    {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;    
    }
```

Then use the HTML:

```html
<div class="deskTop">
  ... Define controls to be centred ...
  </div>
```

The DIV containing the control will always be 60% the width of the current form size, and will be automatically centred when the form resizes.

Comment: Is this answer a joke? Where are you supposed to put this HTML and CSS code?